# Python webcam over socket

Tags: python, sockets, stream, webcam

I got this script for socket screen share from server to client can somone tell me how I convert it from screen to webcam capture(stream)?
just how I convert the line of sct.grab to webcam and make it work.
I tried capturing a picture and then using open() on the image and send its pixels but pygame said:"String length does not equal format and resolution size"

Server:

```
from socket import socket
from threading import Thread
from zlib import compress
from mss import mss



WIDTH = 1900
HEIGHT = 1000

def retreive_screenshot(conn):
    with mss() as sct:
        # The region to capture
        rect = {'top': 0, 'left': 0, 'width': WIDTH, 'height': HEIGHT}

        while 'recording':
            # Capture the screen
            img = sct.grab(rect)
            data = compress(img.rgb, 6)

            # Send the size of the pixels length
            size = len(data)
            size_len = (size.bit_length() + 7) // 8
            conn.send(bytes([size_len]))

            # Send the actual pixels length
            size_bytes = size.to_bytes(size_len, 'big')
            conn.send(size_bytes)

            # Send pixels
            conn.sendall(data)

def main(host='127.0.0.1', port=5555):
    sock = socket()
    sock.bind((host, port))
    try:
        sock.listen(5)
        print('Server started.')

        while 'connected':
            conn, addr = sock.accept()
            print('Client connected IP:', addr)
            thread = Thread(target=retreive_screenshot, args=(conn,))
            thread.start()
    finally:
        sock.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Client:

```
from socket import socket
from zlib import decompress
import pygame


WIDTH = 1900
HEIGHT = 1000


def recvall(conn, length):
    """ Retreive all pixels. """
    buffer = b''
    while len(buffer) < length:
        data = conn.recv(length - len(buffer))
        if not data:
            return data
        buffer += data
    return buffer



def main(host='127.0.0.1', port=5555):

    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    watching = True    

    s = socket()
    s.connect((host, port))
    try:
        while watching:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    watching = False
                    break

            # Retreive the size of the pixels length, the pixels length and pixels
            size_len = int.from_bytes(s.recv(1), byteorder='big')
            size = int.from_bytes(s.recv(size_len), byteorder='big')
            pixels = decompress(recvall(s, size))

            img = pygame.image.fromstring(pixels, (WIDTH, HEIGHT), 'RGB')
            screen.blit(img, (0, 0))
            pygame.display.flip()
            clock.tick(60)
    finally:
        s.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found a soulution I just tried it like the oriiginal insted of coming up with a new idea. I now use files(cache), trandfer the pixels, creating a new image file and uding the load() method in PyGame.image.
FYI, this is a **base** code, you can play with it your way and add more things to it, and make it better.

Here is the code,
Server:

```
from socket import socket
from threading import Thread
from zlib import compress
from cv2 import *


WIDTH = 1900
HEIGHT = 1000

def retreive_screenshot(conn):
    cam = VideoCapture(0)
    while 'recording':
        # initialize the camera
        s, img = cam.read()
        imwrite("filename.jpg", img)  # save image
        f = open('filename.jpg', 'rb')
        data = compress(f.read(), 6)
        f.close()

        # Send the size of the pixels length
        size = len(data)
        size_len = (size.bit_length() + 7) // 8
        conn.send(bytes([size_len]))

        # Send the actual pixels length
        size_bytes = size.to_bytes(size_len, 'big')
        conn.send(size_bytes)

        # Send pixels
        conn.sendall(data)

def main(host='127.0.0.1', port=5555):
    sock = socket()
    sock.bind((host, port))
    try:
        sock.listen(5)
        print('Server started.')

        while 'connected':
            conn, addr = sock.accept()
            print('Client connected IP:', addr)
            thread = Thread(target=retreive_screenshot, args=(conn,))
            thread.start()
    finally:
        sock.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Client:

```
from socket import socket
from zlib import decompress
import pygame


WIDTH = 1900
HEIGHT = 1000


def recvall(conn, length):
    """ Retreive all pixels. """
    buffer = b''
    while len(buffer) < length:
        data = conn.recv(length - len(buffer))
        if not data:
            return data
        buffer += data
    return buffer



def main(host='127.0.0.1', port=5555):

    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    watching = True

    s = socket()
    s.connect((host, port))
    try:
        while watching:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    watching = False
                    break

            # Retreive the size of the pixels length, the pixels length and pixels
            size_len = int.from_bytes(s.recv(1), byteorder='big')
            size = int.from_bytes(s.recv(size_len), byteorder='big')
            pixels = decompress(recvall(s, size))
            ff = open('filenam.jpg', 'wb')
            ff.write(pixels)
            ff.close()
            img = pygame.image.load('filenam.jpg')
            screen.blit(img, (0, 0))
            pygame.display.flip()
            clock.tick(60)
    finally:
        s.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```